# Svelte todo app bug: title property returns undefined

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-2

I am working on a small ToDo application in Svelte for learning purposes (Im new to Svelte).

In the view I have:

```
<div class="input-group p-2" id="editForm">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="old_todo" value={currentToDo.title} placeholder="Edit Todo">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button on:click="{addTodo}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>

//More code

{#each todos as t, index}   
<tr>
  <td>{index + 1}</td>
  <td class="{t.completed == true ? 'completed' : ''}">{t.title}</td>
  <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" on:change={completeTodo(t.id)}></td>
  <td class="text-right">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button on:click="{editTodo(t.id)}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</button>
      <button on:click="{deleteTodo(t.id)}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
{/each}
```

The part of the script I believe is relevant here:

```
<script>
    import {onMount} from "svelte";

    const apiURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_start=1&_limit=20";

    let todos = [];

    onMount(async function() {
        const response = await fetch(apiURL);
        todos = await response.json();
        todos.reverse();
    });

    var currentToDo = {};

    function editTodo(tid) {
        let itemIdx = todos.findIndex(x => x.id == tid);
        let currentToDo = todos[itemIdx];
    }

<script>
```

See the REPL **[here](https://svelte.dev/repl/12cb6530a9bd46729751762e9979b610?version=3.23.2)**.

The problem is that the text field `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="old_todo" value={currentToDo.title} placeholder="Edit Todo">` displays `undefined` instead of the current (do be edited) todo title.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `currentToDo.title` really is `undefined`...

You can change to `currentToDo.title || ''` if you want to avoid this display:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="old_todo" value={currentToDo.title || ''} placeholder="Edit Todo">
```

Also, to make you Edit button work...

Change this:

```
<button on:click="{editTodo(t.id)}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</button>
```

to this:

```
<button on:click="{() => editTodo(t.id)}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</button>
```

`on:click="{editTodo(t.id)}` becomes `on:click="{() => editTodo(t.id)}`, otherwise your `editTodo` function is called once per render, but not when the button is actually clicked (in Svelte you pass a function reference, not a function *body* like normal HTML `onclick` for example).

Also, in your `editTodo` function:

```js
    function editTodo(tid){
        let itemIdx = todos.findIndex(x => x.id == tid);
        let currentToDo = todos[itemIdx];
    }
```

You need to remove this `let` to use the root scope `currentToDo`, instead of a locally scoped variable:

```js
    function editTodo(tid){
        let itemIdx = todos.findIndex(x => x.id == tid);
        currentToDo = todos[itemIdx];
    }
```

Then you can click on an Edit button and the title will be displayed in the input field as expected!

Comment: In Svelte you need to pass a function to event handlers. That is, the content of the curlies must be a function. `{editTodo}` would pass the function `editTodo`, but you need it to use a local param `t.id`, so you make it a function that calls `editTodo` with the param: `{() => editTodo(t.id)}`. `{editTodo(t.id)}` is the result of calling `editTodo(t.id)`; it would get called each time the template is evaluated (updated), not when the click event is triggered.